# Is it possible to execute IDE tasks in Android Studio from a Gradle script?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to find a way to run the Android Studio "Optimize Imports" command on my source code files using Gradle. I'm pulling automatically generated code from a server, but the imports on these files are not optimized correctly and I cannot change this. So far, I have been manually running the "Optimize Imports" command every time I pull new code from the server. Is there a way to automate this task using Gradle?

Comment: At least not that I'm aware of. I'd suggest reporting an enhancement requets to JetBrains for adding the capability to run refactorings in such a way.